# Функция срабатывает два раза

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток! есть такой код:

```
    $(document).on('click','.item-edit-field',function(e){
        var old = $(this);
        var input = $('<input>',{
            val:$(this).text(),
            'class':'replaced-input',
        });
        $(this).parent().append(input);
        input.focus();
        old.detach();

        $(document).on('blur','.replaced-input',function(e){
            alert(old.text());
            if(old.text() != $(this).val())
            {
                old.text($(this).val());
                var arr = {
                    name:old.data('name'),
                    id:old.data('id'),
                    text:old.text()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url:'index.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:{'ext':'menus','task':'updateItem','params':arr},
                    success:function(e){

                    }
                })
            }   
            $(this).parent().append(old);
            $(this).remove();
            delete old;
        })
    })
```

для одного элемента все срабатывает нормально, но если кликнуть на следующий элемент, то функция blur срабатывает два раза - сначала для удаленного элемента, потом для текущего. в чем проблема?

Comment: Оформил комментарий как ответ, примите, если вопрос решен.

Comment: @woland, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

потому что при срабатывании click вы опять вешаете обработчик на blur. вынесите обработчик для blur из обработчика для click.